# Is a list of slice items really possible in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slicing#grammar-token-slicing), the slicing operation requires the primary and a list of comma-separated slice items.

```
slicing      ::=  primary "[" slice_list "]"
slice_list   ::=  slice_item ("," slice_item)* [","]
slice_item   ::=  expression | proper_slice
proper_slice ::=  [lower_bound] ":" [upper_bound] [ ":" [stride] ]
```

The way I interpret it, an expression like this must be possible (here, `primary` is a list):

```
primary[1::2, ::2]
```

However, it causes a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

There is a "clarification" further in the documentation that, in my opinion, makes the story even more bizarre:

> If the slice list contains at least one comma, the key is a tuple containing the conversion of the slice items; otherwise, the conversion of the lone slice item is the key.

Could someone provide an example of when and how to use slice lists with commas?

Comment: You can slice panda's DataFrame, e.g. `df.iloc[1::2, ::2]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely I see. So, a list with a comma is always syntactically correct but not always semantically applicable, right?

Comment: Yes, the same why we have `@` operator. Only useful application I know is in `numpy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works exactly as intended. Lists don't accept tuples as indexes. You are passing the tuple `(slice(1, None, 2), slice(None, None, 2))` into a list, which rejects it.

This works with things like `numpy` matrices:

```python
import numpy

a = numpy.matrix([
	[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
	[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
	[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
	[16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
	[21, 22, 23, 24, 25] ])

print(a[1::2, 2::1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jco7CsMwEIThOjrFljaIkFnHeQhyEqPCXVRIFkKB@PTKOCp@GHa/vNf3lqbWQsxbqZI@Me/GrPLq8xzXWsJ3WMxpEVgRZRO7stnb43zjvLMHe1rB5X8GNahBDWp0DWpQgxrU2rVSK7VSK7XOXvxoTC4h1WFd4NzxdQ5@bO0H)